# Importing an executable jar file in libgdx in android studio

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I tried out the tarsosDSP "*on clap listener*" in a normal android studio project, where i had to import an executable jar file into `.../app/libs`.
Now i have the problem that I can't find `.../app/libs` in a libgdx project.

There are many libs folders, I tried all of them but none of them seems to work.
The whole `libgdx` folder looks different.

Answer (score 0):

create libs folder into your root project folder and keep your jar/jars into this folder.

Need to compile your jar, now open build.gradle of your root project.

In core module of build.gradle add in dependencies

```
compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
```

refresh your gradle.

Comment: thats what I did and I get this:
Error:Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: when i run gradlew build --info i get 
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareExcepti
on:

Comment: Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=9660, address=[c396a575-4f26-425c-91ad-159e6650
e00b port:54445, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], idle=true, lastBusy=1484507023775, context=DefaultDaemonContext[ui
d=34f95ebd-20c8-4a1b-b307-85a025f0e0f5,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Adamovita\.gradl
e\daemon,pid=9660,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xms128m,-Xmx1500m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=DE,-Duser.lan
guage=de,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).